# DependsOn with if else statement in cloudforamtion yml template

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Hi i have 2 `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener` name `Listener1` and `Listener2`. I have a condition in which either `listner1` is deployed or `listner1`
I have created a ecs service which i want to be depended on Listener.

```
Service:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn: !If [Condition, Listener1, Listener2]
    Properties:
```

When deployed its giving me error `Template format error: DependsOn must be a string or list of strings.`

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, you can't do the following:

```
 DependsOn: !If [Condition, Listener1, Listener2]
```

As the error message says, `DependsOn` takes only a string value or a list of strings, not a function, e.g:

```
DependsOn: [SomeExistingResource1, SomeExistingResource2]
```

Also `Fn::If` can only be used in metadata attribute, update policy attribute, and property values. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if):

> Currently, AWS CloudFormation supports the Fn::If intrinsic function in the **metadata attribute, update policy attribute, and property values** in the Resources section and Outputs sections of a template.

Thus you can't use `Fn::If` in `DependsOn`.

Comment: Will this not cause any error when listener1 is not deployed? Because There would be either listner1 or listener2 deployed as per the condition.

Comment: @SudarshanRampuria Yes, it will error out. I will change the answer as not to confuse. It was just an example. You need to redesign your template, as you can't do such conditions in CFN.